# creating a simple python menu

Tags: python, menu

I am trying to create a list that shows you a set of options to do changes to the the list.
but its not working can someone tell me what is wrong with it please.

```
menulist=( "1. Print the list",
        "2. Add a name to the list",
        "3. Remove a name from the list",
        "4. Change an item in the list",
        "9. Quit")

list=("johny","tom","kim","tim","jim")

target=input("Pick an item from the menu:")
 while (target in list):
     if target="1"
        print list
    elif target="2"
        Addname=input("Type in a name to add:")
        list=list.insert(Addname)
            print menulist()
    elif target="3"
        Removename=input("What name would you like to remove:")
        list=list.remove(Removename)
            print menulist()
    elif target="4"
        Changename=input(What name would you like to change:")
        changetoname=input("What is the new name:")
        list=list.replace('Changename','changetoname')
            print menulist()
    elif target="9"
            print"good bye"
```

Comment: You've got no opening " in your `elif target="4"` branch

Comment: You have various syntax errors, such as no `:` after conditionals, you're using the assignment operator (`=`) when you want comparison (`==`), etc.  You should probably start with an introductory book to Python

Comment: Is that code in Python?

Answer (score 3):

Several Things

1. your variable is named list, while not an error exactly this is bad form
2. your list is really a tuple, tuples cannot be changed
3. list.insert is not valid python
4. `input` is dangerous in python 2.x , try `raw_input` instead
5. target will never be in "list" therefor you will never enter your while loop
6. several syntax errors

input will evaluate whatever it is given even something like `import os;os.deltree("C:");` **DONT TRY THIS!** which would allow a malicious user to execute anything they wanted to on the system running your software

Comment: can u explain number 4 please @Joran Basley

Comment: @user2312139, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vulnerability-input-function-python-2-x/

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example of a simple menu in Python. It is an improved version of an old one from this site.

```
import os
import msvcrt as m

 # Function for waiting for key press
def wait():
    m.getch()

 # Clear screen before to show menu, cls is MS Windows command
os.system('cls')

ans=True
while ans:
    print("""
    Simple menu:
    ------------

    1.Add a Student
    2.Delete a Student
    3.Look Up Student Record
    4.Exit/Quit
    """)
    ans=input("What would you like to do? ")
    if ans=="1":
      print("\nStudent Added")
      print("\nPress Enter...")
      wait()
      os.system('cls')
    elif ans=="2":
      print("\nStudent Deleted")
      print("\nPress Enter...")
      wait()
      os.system('cls')
    elif ans=="3":
      print("\nStudent Record Found")
      print("\nPress Enter...")
      wait()
      os.system('cls')
    elif ans=="4":
      print("\nGoodbye") 
      ans = None
    else:
      print("\nNot Valid Choice Try again")
      print("\nPress Enter...")
      wait()
      os.system('cls')
      ans = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed and commented, they're mainly syntax errors.

```
menulist= '''1. Print the list,
    2. Add a name to the list,
    3. Remove a name from the list,
    4. Change an item in the list,
    9. Quit''' #assuming you want to display menulist, having it as a tuple is useless

lst=("johny","tom","kim","tim","jim") #don't use reserved names for variables, may mess up things

target=raw_input("Pick an item from the menu:")

if target=="1": #this is an equality operator, whereas = is used to assign a variable (This checks the equality basically)
    print lst

elif target=="2":
    Addname=raw_input("Type in a name to add:")
    list=list.append(Addname) #use append instead of insert, insert is for a specific position in list
    print menulist #no parentheses, menulist is not a function; also this doesn't have to be indented

elif target=="3":
    Removename=raw_input("What name would you like to remove:")
    list=list.remove(Removename)
    print menulist #again, I took the parentheses away

elif target=="4":
    Changename=raw_input("What name would you like to change:") #you'd missed the " at the beginning
    changetoname=raw_input("What is the new name:")
    list=list.replace(Changename, changetoname) #removed the '. They're the variables, not the strings 'Changename' etc that you want to replace.
    print menulist

elif target=="9":
    print"good bye" #excessive indenting

else: #this replaces the initial while
    #do nothing if the initial input is not 1,2,3,4 or 9
    print menulist
```